# How to get from the loadingcache without triggering a load

Tags: java, google-guava-cache

I'm using java 8 and guava 14.0

I set up a LoadingCache and a CacheLoader with a load().  The code works every time I get from the cache the load () is called

There are times where I want to check if data is in the cache without calling the load().  Is this possible?

I tried using the getIfPresent() but I still see the load() being called.

I was looking at AsMap but concerned with the size of this since it gets all the data from the cache

Thanks in advance for any info/suggestions

Barry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your concern is with `asMap`; that returns a *view*, not an entire copy; the cost of using `asMap` is O(1).  That said, it surprises me that `getIfPresent` still causes a load; that makes me suspicious that some other part of your program is calling load, because `getIfPresent` should not cause that to happen.